# Getting null pointer exception while sharing on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the following code for `FaceBook` share.The picture is posted in some FaceBook ID but for some certain `FaceBook ID` I am getting **Null Pointer Exception** .How could i resolve this issue.

```
   postParams.putString("message", message);
   postParams.putString("picture",picture);
   System.out.println("******* 111111 *********");

   com.facebook.Request.Callback callback = new  com.facebook.Request.Callback()
    {
     public void onCompleted(Response response)
      {
         JSONObject graphResponse =response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
         String postId = null;
         try {
         postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
         } catch (JSONException e) 
         {
         Log.i("postthis", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
         }
         FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
         if (error != null) {
            Log.i("postthis", "JSON error "     +error.getErrorMessage());
            } 
         else {
//       Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), postId,
//                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          }
          };
```

this is `logcat` error :

```
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201):     at FBLogin$2.onCompleted  (FBLogin.java:316)
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1669)
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 09:43:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(5201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-22 09:43:20.843: E/android.os.Debug(353): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: post the logcat along with line number.

Comment: I posted my logcat could anyone help me ..

Comment: What is code at Line No. 316 ?

Comment: this is the line in the above given code if (FBLogin.facebook.isSessionValid())

Comment: @fruity which facebook sdk version you are using..

Comment: you can use following link for sharing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153251/how-do-i-publish-a-check-in-to-facebook-with-android-sdk/21154325#21154325

Comment: i am using facebook3.5.2 library ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your parameters , if any one of the parameter is null then the graph object shows null value in facebook sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The session for posting on wall is null so there is null pointer exception you have to active your session first for posting on wall. You can use the following code for sharing on wall.

```
   Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {

            // Check for publish permissions
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        activity, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("message", message);

                postParams.putString("tags",tag);
                     postParams.putString("place",place_id);



            Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                private String toastmessage;

                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                .getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                        String postId = null;

                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("Test", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        isPosted(false);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity.getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getErrorMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        isPosted(true);
                        toastmessage = "Posted Successfully";
                        Toast.makeText(activity, toastmessage,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed",
                    postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }


    }
});
```

Given at this link [How do I publish a check in to facebook with android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153251/how-do-i-publish-a-check-in-to-facebook-with-android-sdk/21154325#21154325)

Comment: getting this error {Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: 
{HttpStatus: 500, 
errorCode: 341, 
errorType: FacebookApiException,
 errorMessage: Application request limit reached.}, 
isFromCache:false}   in line  JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                .getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

Answer (score 0):

Once try this this is working for me in `Android sdk 3.x`

```
 void publishToWall(Session session) {      
    if (session != null)  {          
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("message", "contentStr");
        postParams.putString("description",  "description");
        postParams.putString("link", "");
        postParams.putString("name", "Name");
        postParams.putString("picture", "picture url");

        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback()  {
            public void onCompleted(Response response)  {       

            }
        };
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();             

        Log.i("TAG", "Message posted to your facebook wall!..");         


    }           
 }
```

Comment: I have used the same code you have posted.. but nothing is posted on the facebook wall . what should I do???